# Universal Windows Platform - Save and retrieve text in list

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a question for you. In XAML i created listview with name listviewtest and textbox with name txtUser. My problem is when i add this textbox txtUser to listviewtest, it will be there, but if i change text in textbox txtUser second time, listviewtest add changed textbox txtUser. What i need to do is add  textbox txtUser to listviewtest and if it will be changed there will be two textboxs - first verion and changed version.
    My code right now is very simple:

```
List<string> namesofusers = new List<string>() { };    
string nameofuser = txtUser.Text;  
namesofusers.Add(naazov); 
listviewtest.ItemsSource = namesofusers;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new List so the old list will go away.

```
List<string> namesofusers = new List<string>() { };
```

Declare `List<string> namesofusers;` elsewhere
Bind once - preferable in XAML to a public property
You many need to use an ObservableCollection rather than List

```
if (namesofusers == null) 
    namesofusers = new List<string>();
```

Comment: This will create a new List so the old list will go away. 
List<string> namesofusers = new List<string>() { }; 
Declare List<string> namesofusers; elsewhere
Bind once - preferable in XAML to a public property
You many need to use an ObservableCollection rather than List
if (namesofusers == null) 
    namesofusers = new List<string>();

Comment: i have done it and it does not work. Meybe in my XAML will be problem..

Comment: becase in list i have there this: <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding}" FontSize="28"></Run>
                        </TextBlock>

Comment: So can you give me your email or someting ?

Comment: Show some effort and clarify the question. Use proper capitalization.   Give you my email?

Comment: So. In my project i created database(login and register page) and this txtUser textbox  is user name from login page. I tried your answer in my project but again it does not work :(. Always when i logined in my app, listviewtest has only 1 text - txtUser - username. When i close my app then listviewtest will be empty and if strat my app again and sing up again with else user name then in listviewtest will be it else user name. What i want to do is have a everything user names what sing up in my app in listviewtest. Please help me if you know problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a coding service and update the question.